# How to set up a CRON with MYSQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning web development. And for that, I am trying to create a web-app to 1. The admin can upload classes per types with dates and time-slots, 2. users can book the classes (this is like the most-basic, or where I can go now).

My code creates a new entry in my MYSQL database. My idea is to add a new column with a quota, so when users book that class the code rests one slot from the quota.

But, what happens? That the admin of the site (this is actually like a booking engine for gym classes), they have to create a class every day per day.

So, I imagine that the best way to achieve this was to 1. the admin can select how many classes to create (for example, a loop that goes between two dates). 2. when the admin fills the form in PHP it creates a new job for CRON.

For instance, the admin decides to create a class selecting MONDAY and THURSDAY at 18.00. The CRON job will insert a new value into the SQL table every MONDAY and THURSDAY, so it will be available for the users to book.

But now, I don't have any idea of how to set this up. I am looking online but I can't find a good tutorial for me...

Thanks beforehands!

Comment: You confuse pattern (MONDAY and THURSDAY at 18.00) and instance (MONDAY 2021-02-22 18:00).

Comment: You do not need in external scheduler. MySQL contains Event Scheduler which may execute Event procedure (for example, weekly) which will generate needed instances by existing patterns for specified future period (for example, all non-existent for the next 4 weeks).

Comment: This doesn't sound like something you should use a CRON job for. It would be better to create all future "classes" when the admin creates them. If you don't want future "classes" available to students yet, you can add that to the code, for instance by only showing a limited amount of future "classes". Solve issues like this by designing the right database structure, not by adding CRON jobs.

Comment: @Akina Actually The thing is that it will be a CMS for gyms, so an admin won't have access to the SQL.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware That's a solution, yes. So I thought the admin of the gym could set like 20 "classes" to be created, but then, if the admin of the gym wants to remove them or edit them it has to be done one by one. That's why I thought in creating a CRON job. Does it make sense? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes it makes sense, but you insist on editing "classes" one by one. That doesn't have to be so. You could make an extra table containing the "planning" for "classes". When a "planning" is updated the associated "classes" should also be updated. When a "planning" is removed, all associated "classes" should also disappear. Etc.

Comment: *an admin won't have access to the SQL.* But he can execute raw SQL queries using extended CMS instruments? Event procedure/schedule creation is one complex SQL query (batch). Of course Event scheduler must be enabled on SQL server, and additional privileges for this procedure creation needed - but ESP must be created once (SQL server admins may create it for you after SP code checking, for example), and then it works independently.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I will think about it, it makes sense thanks!